# Question about EFFECT SIZE

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sample-size, effect-size

I have a question. If I found the effects of a variable is insignificant (p>.05), but the effect size d is 0.2 (small effect).

So I used GPower to calculate the power and I found it is 0.14, which means I need a larger sample size to get a significant results.

So is the hypothesis rejected or supported? because it will be significant if i have a larger sample size.

Thanks

Let me make it clear. My hypothesis is that **priming improves creative performance.**
So if p>.05, d=0, the hypothesis is rejected, **priming has no effect on creative performance**. My question is if p>.05, d=0.2 (small effect), is the hypothesis rejected or supported?

Comment: Any hypothesis test will be significant if you have a larger sample...

Comment: "*because it will be significant if i have a larger sample size*" - with a continuous outcome, there will always be *some* estimated non-zero effect size ... so you could *always* come to the same conclusion as you just did. Does an argument that says "my hypothesis is always supported" make sense? If so, why bother with any sample at all?

Answer (score 3):

You did not reject your hypothesis.

But here you have the opportunity for a few insights:

1. *Any* non-zero effect size is significant with a large enough sample.
2. One might interpret the *significance* of results, absent other considerations, as pretty meaningless beyond "will my editor accept these results?"
3. One might take the approach that, *a priori* an effect size needs be be *so large* in order for one to consider it *relevant*.

   3a. One can combine *tests for difference* with *tests for equivalence* to produce inferences within a hypothesis testing framework that differentiate *relevant* difference from *trivial* difference (i.e. an over-powered test) from *equivalence* from *indeterminacy* (i.e. an underpowered test).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have two variables. Both of them are insignificant, but one of the effect size is 0.2, another one is 0. So the hypothesis with effect size 0 is rejected. The hypothesis with effect size 0.2 is supported. Is it what you meant?

Comment: No! :) First, **you did not reject either hypothesis.** Second, how would you answer this question: what is the smallest effect size that *matters* to you?

Comment: The smallest effect size that matters to me is 0.2. It means that variable has a small effect on the dependent variable, even if it is statistically insignificant.

Comment: I don't understand why the hypothesis is not rejected if p>0.05 and the effect size is 0.

Comment: It sounds like you are desperate to find an effect. :) (1) You did not reject your null hypothesis of no-difference, therefore you cannot conclude that you found a significant difference. (2) The $p$-value is not measured on the same scale as your effect size. The $p$-value is the probability of observing an effect size as or more extreme than the one you did observe if the null hypothesis is in fact true. You will never reject an effect size of 0 in a test for difference (from zero); by definition.

Comment: OH sorry for the confusion! What I meant is to reject my hypothesis, not null hypothesis. So if p>.05, d=0, the hypothesis is rejected. My question is if p>.05, d=0.2 (small effect), is the hypothesis rejected or supported? Sorry about that haha

Comment: Nope. You are not rejecting your null hypotheses (H$_{0}\text{: d=0}$). You are again confusing $p$-value with effect size: they are two different things. (Have you noticed that I am only answering that **you are not rejecting your hypotheses**?). If (for $\alpha=0.05$) $p\ge 0.05$ you **do not reject**.

Comment: I think the OP means this: For $p \ge .05$ (with $d=0$), the "hypothesis" was that there actually is an effect and _that_ hypothesis was rejected. Of course, that turns the idea of null hypothesis testing upside down. The actual (null) hypothesis that is being tested here is that the true effect is in fact zero and that null hypothesis was _not_ rejected.

Comment: A bit confusing, but I think I understand. My hypothesis is that **priming improves creative performance**. So if p>.05, d=0, the hypothesis is rejected, means **priming has no effect on creative performance**. Also, p value and effect size are 2 different things. If I have large enough sample size, hypothesis testing is always significant. Therefore, even if I found a small effect (d = 0.2), as long as p>.05, my hypothesis (**priming improves creative performance**) is rejected. Am I correct?

Comment: Nope. This is my last comment, since we do not seem to be communicating.